# Matlab - Queue Graphics Changes

Tags: matlab, graphics

Is there any way to "queue" | "freeze" | "pospone" graphics properties changes in `figure` and `axes` objects, in order the user don't see them gradually change in the final graphic object when a `for` loop is involved,.i.e.:

```
f=figure;
queue(f); %Ideal function
for i=1:100
    calculation(); 
    commit(f); % Showing changes at this point only
end
```

The property `Visible='off'` is too radical, hiding the object, `XData` forces to structure everything inside the `calculation` function. `drawnow` can indeed commit changes, but still without any way to queue them.

This "Graphics Unstability" can be very tedious when figures appears everywhere changing their sizes, ranges, etc. and changing the functions is out of the question.

Comment: `drawnow` may be what you are looking for as "commit" . If you want to postpone just dont plot it

Comment: Question edited. `drawnow` commits but in no way it means in between changes are queued. I am afraid, dont plotting the results is not a valid alternative.

Comment: in between changes? O.o

Comment: At the moment the question reads "I dont want to plot all the time, what can I do to do that? Also, I am plotting all the time and I cant change that". Well. dont.

Comment: @Ander I am clearly stating about changing graphics properties. You interpretation is not helpfut at all. By graphics properties changes, i mean, any of the properties at a `figure` or `axes` object. This do not constraint the problem at all to the `plot` command.